# Rails Routing Issue - Uninitialized Constant Games

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, uninitialized-constant

I am having a problem with my rails routes file. I have the following match in my routes file:

```
  match '/games/:game_id/increment_cool' => 'games/:game_id#increment_cool', :as => 'games_incrementcool'
```

I then try to use this route from my games view like so:

```
<%= link_to 'Cool!', games_incrementcool_path(@game) %>
```

but I am receiving the routing error `uninitialized constant Games`.

rake routes shows this:

```
(in /home/sumdeos/RIT48/oneCoolGameADay)
                          profile_index GET    /profile/index(.:format)
                       new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)
                           user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)
                   destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)
                 user_omniauth_callback        /users/auth/:action/callback(.r)
                          user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)
                      new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)
                     edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)
                                        PUT    /users/password(.:format)
               cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)
                      user_registration POST   /users(.:format)
                  new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)
                 edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)
                                        PUT    /users(.:format)
                                        DELETE /users(.:format)
submitLeaderboardStatistic_game_leaderboard POST   /games/:game_id/leaderboards/:
                      game_leaderboards GET    /games/:game_id/leaderboards(.
                                        POST   /games/:game_id/leaderboards(.
                   new_game_leaderboard GET    /games/:game_id/leaderboards/n
                  edit_game_leaderboard GET    /games/:game_id/leaderboards/:
                       game_leaderboard GET    /games/:game_id/leaderboards/:
                                        PUT    /games/:game_id/leaderboards/:
                                        DELETE /games/:game_id/leaderboards/:
                                  games GET    /games(.:format)
                                        POST   /games(.:format)
                               new_game GET    /games/new(.:format)
                              edit_game GET    /games/:id/edit(.:format)
                                   game GET    /games/:id(.:format)
                                        PUT    /games/:id(.:format)
                                        DELETE /games/:id(.:format)
                    games_incrementcool        /game/:game_id/increment_cool(
                             home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)
                                   root        /
```

I have tried a number of different ways to make this work, but none of them have worked.

How can I get my view to call the increment_cool method in my games controller? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't that be game_incrementcool_path? The error suggests the RoR magic is looking for a Games model instead of a Game model..

Answer (score 0):

This is the way match works: `match '/posts' => 'posts#index'`

The first string is the route and the second string is a controller/action combination separated by #.

`'games#increment_cool'` represents the `increment_cool` action of the `games` controller.

`match '/games/:game_id/increment_cool' => 'games#increment_cool', :as => 'games_incrementcool'`

Although you should probably use the singular 'game' in your `:as` option for semantic reasons because it's working on a singular resource. Maybe something like `game_increment_cool` or `increment_cool_game`.